# Help with a variable change

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I'm integrating a function of the variables $x_i,y_i,z_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ and I define new variables given by
$$u_1=x_1+y_3 z_3,$$
$$u_2=x_2+y_1 z_1,$$
$$u_3=x_3+y_2 z_2.$$
NOTE: I don't actually want to evaluate the integral, I just want to it to end up in a particular form.

Let's say my integral has the following form
$$\int_0^{\infty}\prod_i dx_i dy_i dz_i f(x,y,z),$$
where $$f(x,y,z)=(y_2(x_1+x_2)+x_2x_3+x_1(x_2+x_3))(y_1(x_1+x_3)+x_2x_3+x_1(x_2+x_3))(y_3(x_2+x_3)+x_2x_3+x_1(x_2+x_3))z_1z_2z_3.$$

To introduce the new variable I used a dirac delta function (I'm a physics student so have mercy) that should evaluate to 1,
$$\int_0^{\infty}\prod_i dx_i dy_i dz_i f(x,y,z)\int_0^{\infty}\prod_i du_i\delta(u_1-x_1-y_3 z_3)\delta(u_2-x_2-y_1 z_1)\delta(u_3-x_3-y_2 z_2),$$

Now, I want to isolate these new coordinates so that an overall factor multiplies my integral. This happens for the function if I rescale

$$x_i\rightarrow u_i q$$
$$y_1\rightarrow -u_2 q$$
$$y_2\rightarrow -u_3 q$$
$$y_3\rightarrow -u_1 q,$$
where I hold $u_i$ constant. I don't think this transformation really makes sense though as I should have 3 new variables rather than one, but defining 3 variables results in the function $f$ having an undesirable form. I am fairly certain it's possible to get it into the form I want, so maybe there is a better transformation I can make.

Can someone help me make sense of this?

Comment: $f$ is a polynomial.  Why is it a problem to integrate that? The infinite range looks odd though. Where does this problem occur?

Comment: I do not want to actually evaluate the integral, I want the integral to be a particular form, which involves having an overall factor of the u variables multiplying everything. I'll make an edit.

Comment: The integral is a sum of terms $\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty x_i^{p_i} y_i^{q_i}z_i^{r_i}\,dx_i\,dy_i\,dz_i$ with degrees $p_i,q_i,r_i\in\mathbb N\,.$ Each term is infinite, regardless in what form.

Comment: There are other terms involved that regulate the integral but I do not include them as it not necessary for this step. The result of the integral is not the important part for now, I just want to find the variable change that can give me this form I mentioned.

Comment: Be it as it may. To make progress with the discussion we can assume for now you integrate only over $[0,1]\,.$ Can you explain in a one dimensional example how introducing a $\delta$-function brings the integrand $f$ into a desirable form? I don't get it.

Comment: What looks strange to me is that your change of variable convert 9 variables into 3. I am accustomed to "legit" change of variables amounting to a bijection from a certain domain to another one (in general bijectivity is established by exhibiting the inverse change of variables). But here ?